# OK missing from HTTP response header

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

I have a webapp deployed in Tomcat 8. This is the servlet I am having problems with:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Start", urlPatterns = {"/start"})
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestBodyStr = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        StartRequest startRequest = JsonUtil.parseStartRequest(requestBodyStr);

        if (startRequest == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return;
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        String responseBody = getResponseBody();

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.print(responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

If I make a request to this servlet then the response contains no OK status message, it is just:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
```

How do I add OK to the response?

Comment: The 200 IS an ok response. You should take note of teh return code value, and not expect some text. However, if that is required, then you need to add it to the response stream.

Comment: You cannot change the standard response codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);`, it is the same as doing `response.setStatus(200);` (Literally, if you check it, `SC_OK` is just a constant with value `200`). 200 is the code for `OK` in http. If you want to **write** `OK` manually, you have to add:

```
responserBody += " OK";
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    out.print(responseBody);
}
```

but that shouldn't be useful, as `200` is already saying: The request worked as intended.